# Spark StreamingContext awaitTerminationOrTimeout

Tags: apache-spark

I'm calling `streamingContext.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(timeout)`, but I want to make `timeout` environment dependent.

This means that I want to stop my job if my environment is UAT, but I don't want it to timeout at all if my environment is production.

I have checked the documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext.html#awaitTerminationOrTimeout(long)), but I can't find any references to whether passing `0` or `-1` as timeout will just make the job run forever (or until it fails).

Are there any possible `timeout` values that could do the trick? Or any other alternatives that don't imply calling `awaitTermination` for my production environment and `awaitTerminationOrTimeout` for my UAT environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking a look at the library, I can see that any negative value will do.

`awaitTerminationOrTimeout(timeout)` internally calls `streamingContext.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(timeout)`, which then calls `contextWriter.waitForStopOrError(timeout)`.

Inside `waitForStopOrError` there is a condition that says that if the `timeout` is lower than zero, then we wait.

**TL:DR**: `-1` will never let the job timeout.